# Intel c++ compiler in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use Intel c++ compiler for my Xcode project. After installation, following the tutorial from Intel, there's an Intel c++ compiler should be available on the build list in Xcode. However, my Xcode only lists the default compiler. Could anyone explain how to add addition compiler to Xcode?
Thx